# Java Mqtt Client disconnects after one message received by the callback

Tags: java, mqtt, paho

in my code, there are four classes: mainProgram, Coordinator class, Client Class and Callback Class. 
The mainProgram, which contains the main method of the program, creates an instance of the Coordinator Class and calls its start() method.
The later creates two instances of the Client Class, a publisher and a subscriber, connects both of them and subscribes one of the instances, the subscriber, to multiple topics.
The Client Class contains everything what has to do with mqtt and concerning the Callback for the subscribe-method, I've created an own class for this, the Callback Class which receives in the messageArrived method the incoming mqtt messages.

This is the code of the main:

```
public class mainProgram throws MqttException {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Coordinator coordinator=new Coordinator();
    coordinator.start();
}}
```

this is the code of the Coordinator class:

```
public class Coordinator  { 
      Client publisher;
      Client subscriber;

      public Coordinator() {
         // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
      }

      public void start() throws MqttException {
             Client publisher=new Client("publisher","tcp://192.168.0.10",0);
             publisher.connect();
             Client subscriber=new Client("subscriber","tcp://192.168.0.10",0);
             subscriber.connect();
             subscriber.subscribeToTopic(new String [] {"home/Sensor2","home/Sensor3"});    
      }

      public void getMessage(String message) throws MqttPersistenceException, MqttException {
            publisher.publish("home/Sensor4", message); 
      }}
```

This is the Client Class:

```
public class Client  {
      String brokerAddress;
      String clientId;
      int qos;
      MqttClient mqttClient;
      MqttConnectOptions conOpt;
      MemoryPersistence persistence;
      Coordinator coordinator;

      public Client(String clientId, String brokerAddress, int qos) {   
            this.clientId=clientId;
            this.brokerAddress=brokerAddress;
            this.qos=qos;
            this.setConOpt();
      }

      public void setConOpt() { 
           conOpt=new MqttConnectOptions();
           conOpt.setKeepAliveInterval(30);                         
           conOpt.setAutomaticReconnect(false);                         
      }

      public void connect() throws MqttException {

        mqttClient=new MqttClient(brokerAddress,clientId,persistence);
        this.mqttClient.setCallback(new Callback(this));                    

        this.mqttClient.connect(this.conOpt);

        while(this.mqttClient.isConnected()==false) {
            System.out.println("Connecting");
            System.out.println("...");
        }

        if(this.mqttClient.isConnected()==true){
            System.out.println("Der Mqttclient "+this.mqttClient.getClientId()+" is now connected!");   
        }
     }

     public void subscribeToTopic(String [] topics) throws MqttException {
              for(int i=0;i<topics.length;i++) {
                     this.mqttClient.subscribe(topics[i]);
              } 
    }

    public void publish(String topic, String message) throws MqttPersistenceException, MqttException {      
            MqttMessage mqttMessage=new MqttMessage(message.getBytes());
            this.mqttClient.publish(topic, mqttMessage);
    }
}
```

This is the Callback Class:

```
public class Callback implements MqttCallback{

Client client;

public Callback(Client client)  {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.client=client;
}

@Override
public void connectionLost(Throwable arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Connection to server's lost");
}

@Override
public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Message's delivered");
}

@Override
public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws Exception {
        String ingoingMsg=message.toString();
        System.out.println("until here all's fine");
        Coordinator coordinator=new Coordinator();
        coordinator.getMessage(ingoingMsg);
}
}
```

The program starts, creates the clients and when I publish via MQTTfx a message to the above mentionned topics, in the console this shows up:

[image]

The program ends and the connection of the client "subscriber" ends when I call the method "coordinator.getMessage()" and nothing is published.

At the end, the program should behave like this:

1. create clients
2. connect clients
3. subscribe the subscriber client
4. Listen and if a message to the topic subscribed is published: Call the getMessage of the coordinator class to publish something
5. while and after publishing the listening to further messages should not end and the programm is "in a loop" until the user breaks it up.

I searched everywhere for a solution, but there are not quite the same problems that I have on the web.
Maybe you have some illuminating tips for me ...

Comment: Your class looks a bit awkward to me... But the first question to "illuminate" would be: which of the 2 clients gets disconnected? Add a string ("publisher" or "subscriber") to your Callback class to clarify this

Comment: Thank you for your answer Alexander. it's the subscriber who gets disconnected. in which way my class looks akward to you?

Comment: For example the loop waiting for connection is unnecessary, because you are using synchronous API. Also, in general when using such loops, put at least `Thread.sleep(1000)` there, because you're wasting CPU otherwise. Also, why the numerous `this.`, you don't need them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your remark. I'm still on the amateur level in programming - so every hint to improve is welcome. do you have maybe an idea why my client's disconnecting ?

Comment: Have you looked into the broker logs?

Comment: I looked in the broker logs and I could only deduct the fact that at the beginning there're 3 clients connected (subscriber, publisher, mqttfx client) and after having run the code the subscriber disconnects.  I tried another version, where the subscribe client publishes a message within the messageArrived Method of the callback class and this works. so the subscriber disconnects exactly when I call another method outside of the callback message. Do you know why this is the case? actually I want to run my clients in the background and the data arrived should be processed in other methods

Comment: Try a public MQTT broker

Comment: thanks for the hint. good idea to look if it's the broker who's causing the trouble. Same problem with the public broker. I implemented now a AsyncMqtt Client and it's working... apparently the "normal" client was blocking the other method and disconnected. thanks a lot, Alexander, for your help. have a nice weekend